# Printing a Pyramid Pattern in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a recursive function to print an upside-down pyramid in Python while also using indentation. What I have so far is:

```
def printStars(n, indent):
  if n == 0:
      return
  elif n == 1:
      print(indent * ' ' * '*')
  else:
      print(n * '*' + indent * ' ')
      printStars(n-2,indent)
```

printStars(10, 2) prints:

```
**********
*******
******
****
**
```

but I want it to print:

```
  **********
   ********
    ******
     ****
      **
```

any help would be appreciated

edit:
I now have:

```
def printStars(n, indent):
  if n == 0:
      return
  elif n == 1:
      print(n)
  else:
      print(indent * ' ' + n * '*')
      printStars(n-2,indent)
```

It idents the pyramid but not in the correct way.

Comment: `indent * ' ' * '*'` doesn't make much sense..

Comment: So your output is missing indentation *before* the `*` characters. Where do you think that that might be going wrong? Look closely at your last `print()` function.

Comment: n * '*' + indent * ' ' Notice any indents in the front before your *'s?

Comment: I fixed the indentation problem, now I just need help figuring out how to make the pattern a centered pyramid.

Comment: `printStars(n-2,indent+1)` maybe?

Comment: wow that was too simple....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your input is the base size, that being the case, we first need to tackle the even or odd problem.

```
def pyramid(size):
  if (size%2 == 0): #even
    print '*' * size
    i = 1
    while i < size/2:
      str1 = (' ' * i)
      str2 = ( '*' * (size - 2*i))
      print str1 + str2 + str1
      i+=1
  else:
    print '*' * size
    i = 1
    while i < size/2:
      str1 = (' ' * i)
      str2 = ( '*' * (size - 2*i))
      print str1 + str2 + str1
      i+=1
    str1 = (' ' * i)
    print str1+'*'+str1
```

I did not see the inputs required an indent, but that could be easily factored in to this code. Consider it a good exercise in understanding the problem trying to use my example as a guideline.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printStars(n, indent):
  if n == 0:
      return
  elif n == 1:
      print(indent * ' ' + '*')
  else:
      print(indent * ' ' + n * '*')
      printStars(n - 2, indent + 1)
```

The main difference to your code? The parameter to your function call, and what should happen when n==1.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that appears to work would be:

```
def stars_pyramid(n, indent):

    if n <= 0:
        return
    s = '*' * n
    i = indent * ' '
    print i + s

    stars_pyramid(n-2, indent+1)



n = 10
indent = 0

stars_pyramid(n, indent) outputs:

**********
 ********
  ******
   ****
    **
```

Comment: indent must always be 0 to start off. Though I just realised that you seem to want to be able to input different indentation values...

Comment: correction, indent doesn't have to be 0, but it hardly makes a difference in this example